# ¿Cómo puedo hacer que se ejecute una accion cada segundo?

Tags: java, java-swing, metodología

es una animación y en un txt escribo las acciones que se mostraran en un `JPanel` después de que leyó el archivo se ejecutan las acciones derecha, arriba, abajo, izquierda en teoria; Pero solo se ejecuta la ultima y quiero saber como puedo hacer que se ejecuta una a una cada segundo

```
leerOperaciones();
    for (String[] operacion : inter.getOperaciones()) {
        for (int i = 0; i < operacion.length; i++) {
            switch(operacion[i]){
                case "DER":
                    robot.setPasos(1);
                    robot.setDer(true);
                    break;
                case "IZQ":
                    robot.setPasos(1);
                    robot.setIzq(true);
                    break;
                case "ARR":
                    robot.setPasos(1);
                    robot.setArr(true);
                    break;
                case "ABA":
                    robot.setPasos(1);
                    robot.setAba(true);
                    break;
                default:
                    System.out.println("PC");
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

puedes hacerlo utilizando la función `timer`.

```
    private boolean termino=false;
    private Timer timer = new Timer(ONE_SECOND, new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                    //aquí adaptas tu lectura de archivo
                    if(termino){ //crea alguna bandera para saber cuando terminó de leer tu archivo
                       timer.stop(); //detienes el timer
                    }
                    switch(operacion[i]){
                    case "DER":
                        robot.setPasos(1);
                        robot.setDer(true);
                        break;
                    case "IZQ":
                        robot.setPasos(1);
                        robot.setIzq(true);
                        break;
                    case "ARR":
                        robot.setPasos(1);
                        robot.setArr(true);
                        break;
                    case "ABA":
                        robot.setPasos(1);
                        robot.setAba(true);
                        break;
                    default:
                        System.out.println("PC");
                        break;
                }
                }
            });
timer.start(); //inicias el timer
```

imagina que el timer es como un for, que se reproduce cada cierto tiempo (configurado para un segundo en tu caso particular). para detenerlo, debes usar `timer.stop();` (lo agregué en el código, antes de tu switch)

Comment: El código si lo copias y pegas como tal no te va a funcionar por el switch que hace refenrencia a `i` de tu ciclo, tienes que adaptar el código para que funcione con el timer.

Comment: y si ya tengo un `timer` en la misma clase y el switch en un metodo solo configuro el timer asi????

Comment: una disculpa, ya no entré al sitio hasta hoy. editaría mi respuesta pero ya encontraste tu solución

Answer (score 0):

me sirvió mucho el `timer` lo metí a un método

```
public void ejecutar(){
    inter.leerOperaciones();
    operacion = inter.getOperaciones().get(j);
    tiempo = new Timer( (int) javax.management.timer.Timer.ONE_SECOND, this);
    tiempo.start();
}
```

y el `ActionListener` lo cambie asi...

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    switch(operacion[i]){
        case "DER":
            robot.der();
            repaint();
            i++;
            break;
        case "IZQ":
            robot.izq();
            repaint();
            i++;
            break;
        case "ARR":
            robot.arr();
            repaint();
            i++;
            break;
        case "ABA":
            robot.aba();
            repaint();
            i++;
            break;
        case "PC":
            i = 0;
            j++;
            if (j == inter.getOperaciones().size()) {
                j = 0;
                robot.todoFalse();
                repaint();
                tiempo.stop();
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "fin de ejecucion");
            } else if (j < inter.getOperaciones().size()){
                operacion = inter.getOperaciones().get(j);
            }
            break;
    }
}
```